# Como faço para imprimir em tela os semestres

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Tenho esse código, a query já está feita, falta só chamar na tag. Como faço para 
imprimir em tela os meses do semestre depois das metas.

```php
<?php
 /* codigo para gerar os paramentros  */
    $ano        = $_POST["ano"];
    $_perspectiva = $_POST["perspectiva"];

    if ($_POST["semestre"] == "primeiro") {
        $_parametros = array (
        "ano" => $ano,
        "mes1" => 1, "mes2" => 2, "mes3" => 3,
        "mes4" => 4, "mes5" => 5, "mes6" => 6,
        "nomeMes1" => "Janeiro", "nomeMes2" => "Fervereiro", "nomeMes3" => "Março",
        "nomeMes4" => "Abril", "nomeMes5" => "Maio", "nomeMes6" => "Junho",
        "perspectiva" => $_perspectiva);
    }else if ($_POST["semestre"] == "segundo") {
        $_parametros = array (
        "ano" => $ano,
        "mes1" => 7, "mes2" => 8, "mes3" => 9,
        "mes4" => 10, "mes5" => 11, "mes6" => 12,
        "nomeMes1" => "Julho", "nomeMes2" => "Agosto", "nomeMes3" => "Setembro",
        "nomeMes4" => "Outubro", "nomeMes5" => "Novembro", "nomeMes6" => "Dezembro",
        "perspectiva" => $_perspectiva);
    }else {
        $error = "ERRO";
    }


    //Instanciando a classe
    $_model = new model_Indoperacionais();
    $_indoperacionais = $_model->RetornaIndoperacionais($ano);

        //echo "<pre>"; print_r ($_indoperacionais);exit;
          echo '<h3 align=left>'.'&nbsp&nbspArea de Gestao de Pessoas'.'</h3>';

     foreach($_indoperacionais as $_indoperacional){
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td align=center>'.$_indoperacional['nome_tema'].'</td>';
          echo '<td align=center>'.$_indoperacional['indicadores'].'</td>';
          echo '<td align=center>'.$_indoperacional['responsavel'].'</td>';
          echo '<td align=center>'.$_indoperacional['metas'].'</td>';
          echo '<td align=center>'.$_indoperacional['iniciativa_sequencia'].'</td>';
          echo '</tr>';
        //print_r($_parametros);
     }
    ?>


class model_Indoperacionais extends MysqlConnection{


private $indoperacionais;

public function RetornaIndoperacionais($ano){

    if($ano == '2016'){
        $_base = "pla_est_2016";
        $_base = "pla_est";

    }else{

    }

    $Query = ("SELECT i.codiniciativa,
    te.nome as nome_tema,
    te.codtemaestrategico as cod_te,
    p.observacoes as per_obs,
    te.sequencia as tem_sequencia,
    p.sigla as per_sigla,
    p.nome as nome_perspectiva,
    p.codperspectiva as cod_perspectiva,
    o.sequencia as sequencia_obj,
    o.codobjetivo as cod_obj,
    o.nome as nome_obj,concat(p.sigla, ' ', te.sequencia,
    '.', o.sequencia, '.',i.sequencia) as codigo,i.nome as nom_iniciativa,
    i.sequencia as iniciativa_sequencia,
    i.metas,i.responsavel,i.indicadores,
    ifnull((SELECT a. percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2016 AND month(a.data) = 1 ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2016 AND month(a.data) < 1 AND curdate() >= '2016-01-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '01',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2016 AND month(a.data) = 2 ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2016 AND month(a.data) < 2 AND curdate() >= '2016-02-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '02',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2016 AND month(a.data) = 3 ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2016 AND month(a.data) < 3 AND curdate() >= '2016-03-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '03',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2016 AND month(a.data) = 4 ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2016 AND month(a.data) < 4 AND curdate() >= '2016-04-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '04',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2016 AND month(a.data) = 5 ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2016 AND month(a.data) < 5 AND curdate() >= '2016-05-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '05',
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) = 2016 AND month(a.data) = 6 ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1),
    ifnull((SELECT a.percentual FROM avaliacoes a WHERE a.status = 'A' AND a.codiniciativa = i.codiniciativa AND year(a.data) <= 2016 AND month(a.data) < 6 AND curdate() >= '2016-06-01' ORDER BY a.data DESC LIMIT 1), 0)) as '06'FROM perspectivas p  LEFT JOIN temasestrategicos te ON p.codperspectiva = te.codperspectiva LEFT JOIN objetivos o ON te.codtemaestrategico = o.codtemaestrategico LEFT JOIN iniciativas i ON o.codobjetivo = i.codobjetivo WHERE p.codperspectiva = '5' AND p.status = 'A' AND te.status = 'A' AND o.status = 'A' AND i.status = 'A'ORDER BY p.sequencia ASC,te.sequencia ASC,
    o.sequencia ASC,CAST(i.sequencia AS DECIMAL) ASC" ); 


    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($Query); exit;

    //while ($_indoperacionais = mysql_fecth_array($Query));
    try {
            $this->search = $this->MySql->prepare($Query);
            //$this->search->bindParam(":nome", $this->indoperacionais);
            $this->search->execute();

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        $_result = $this->search->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $_result;


   }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi o que é que você está tentando fazer. Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: O que posso perceber, é que o echo da query está comentado, a tag pre não está fechada, e o while também está comentado.

Comment: estou imprimindo em tela html o que é listado do banco de dados , só que falta imprimir também o semestre , tipo a pessoa seleciona o primeiro , ai em imprimido em telas os meses do primeiro semestre . e também queria   setar a $_base na query como que faço .

Comment: esses não estão alterando nada .

Comment: @allanaraujo seria interessante dar uma caprichada mais na perguntas, quase todas suas foram fechadas. Especialmente não repita a mesma pergunta feita anteriormente. Se mantenha na primeira. Se ela tinha problemas, arrume o problema e ela será reaberta.